# Series of Weighted Squares of Fourier coefficients.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am considering if the Fourier series development of $f(\theta)$ is
\begin{equation}
f(\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(n\theta) + b_n \sin(n\theta)
\end{equation}

Is there any relationship between the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n^2 + b_n^2}{n}
\end{equation}
and $f(\theta)$?